# Variable Not Leaving If Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display the currently selected featured image in Wordpress for a gallery - if no featured image is selected, I want it to pick the first image in the gallery and use that image. I have written the following and it only returns the image from the else statement. In other words, if I have selected a featured image, no image is displayed. If I tell php to echo out the contents of $image_img_tag within the if statement, it returns the image. But for some reason, it won't display that image outside of the if/else statement. I am assuming that the value of $image_img_tag is not making it out of the if/else statement, but can't figure out why. Any thoughts?

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        $featuredID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $featuredID, 'featured-image');
    else :
        $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 999 ) );
        if ( $images ) :
            $total_images = count( $images );
            $image = array_shift( $images );
            $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'featured-image');
    endif;
?>

<figure class="alignright gallery-thumb">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $image_img_tag; ?></a>
</figure><!-- .alignright .gallery-thumb -->
```

Here is the full code from this area, including all the ifs/endifs. This might help explain the problem.

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for search pages ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'matthewbarker' ) ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                //the_post_thumbnail('featured-image',array('class'=>'alignright'));
                $featuredID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $featuredID, 'featured-image');
            else :
                $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 999 ) );
                if ( $images ) :
                    $total_images = count( $images );
                    $image = array_shift( $images );
                    $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'featured-image');
            endif;
            ?>

        <figure class="alignright gallery-thumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $image_img_tag; ?></a>
        </figure><!-- .alignright .gallery-thumb -->

        <p><em><?php printf( _n( 'This gallery contains <a %1$s>%2$s photo</a>.', 'This gallery contains <a %1$s>%2$s photos</a>.', $total_images, 'matthewbarker' ),
                'href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" title="' . sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'matthewbarker' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) . '" rel="bookmark"',
                number_format_i18n( $total_images )
            ); ?></em></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'matthewbarker' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Are your `if`s not closed properly?

Comment: Is the second `if` supposed to stay open? Consider using normal syntax, with curly braces for code blocks. (Your code is nicely indented, but thusly confusing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed an `endif`:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    $featuredID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $featuredID, 'featured-image');
else :
    $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 999 ) );
    if ( $images ) :
        $total_images = count( $images );
        $image = array_shift( $images );
        $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'featured-image');
    endif; #MISSING? 
endif;
```

Comment: I had tried adding an endif; statement where you mentioned previously, but I get an error stating there is an unexpected endif. I updated the question to include some of the surrounding code. When I look through this, I see that adding the endif; to the _if ( $images ) :_ should work, but then I get the error.

Comment: You missed one `endif` after your last `endif`. There should be two `endif`s before `wp_link_pages`.

Comment: Do a `print_r` on `$images` to confirm that it got a value.

Comment: Thanks rrikesh! It did need the endif; like you mentioned. The problem when I added that was there was an extra endif elsewhere in the code that was screwing it up. Guess that happens when a n00b hacks pieces of code together without paying too much attention.